# How to performing selection by expression using QGIS

Tags: qgis, intersection, area, intersect, select-by-expression

I am using QGIS 3.8.

I have a grid (hexagon) and a set of points.

I am trying to select the hexagons containing at least 1 point. So far nothing complicated.  Except that sometimes my points overlap 2 hexagons.

So I try to select only the hexagons containing at least 1/2 of the area of the points.

Despite my many attempts, I can't come up with an expression that works.

Comment: So are these points? Or polygons that look like points? It would be quite rare for a point to fall exactly on the border of two polygons.

Comment: Points have not dimensions. You have a false perception due to visualization way in your GIS system.